# Android app shortcuts with progressive web app

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Does progress web app support adding app shortcuts (ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html)?

Thanks

Comment: are you asking about google progress web app  or progress web app  frameworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. App shortcuts are an Android API. Maybe browsers will surface a similar API in the future but currently none do.

Comment: This answer was correct at the time, but it's now possible to add app shortcuts to installed PWAs using the link Francois noted below.

Answer (score 2):

The web platform now supports App shortcuts. At the time of writing, app shortcuts are available on Android (Chrome 84) and Windows (Chrome 85 and Edge 85). More desktop platform support will follow.

See https://web.dev/app-shortcuts/